# How to get Pydantic model types?

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider the following model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Cirle(BaseModel):
    radius: int
    pi = 3.14
```

If I run the following code, I can see the fields of this model:

```py
print(Circle.__fields__)

# Output:

{
  'radius': ModelField(name='radius', type=int, required=True), 
  'pi': ModelField(name='pi', type=float, required=False, default=3.14)
}
```

The question is: how can I get the type (or inferred type hint) from the `ModelField` type? These all give errors:

```py
Circle.__fields__['pi'].type
# AttributeError: 'ModelField' object has no attribute 'type'

Circle.__fields__['pi'].__dict__
# AttributeError: 'ModelField' object has no attribute '__dict__'

type(Circle.__fields__['pi'])
# <class 'pydantic.fields.ModelField'>

import typing
typing.get_type_hints(Circle.__fields__['pi'])
# TypeError: ModelField(name='pi', type=float, required=False, default=3.14)
# is not a module, class, method, or function.

typing.get_type_hints(Circle)
# This does not include the "pi" field because it has no type hints
# {'radius': <class 'int'>}
```

I don't even see where the `ModelField` type is defined in [github](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/search?q=ModelField).

How can I iterate over the fields of a pydantic model and find the types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the type_ variable of the pydantic fields. The variable is masked with an underscore to prevent collision with the Python internal type keyword.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Cirle(BaseModel):
    radius: int
    pi = 3.14

for key, value in Cirle.__fields__.items():
    print(key, value.type_)

# Output:
# radius <class 'int'>
# pi <class 'float'>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! How were you able to find that?

Comment: The ModelField class is part of the fields.py file of pydantic. The class defines __slots__ which includes type_ as instance variable.

PyCharm IDE gives also a type hint for this as I noticed later on :-)

Comment: Thank you. I don't see ModelField defined - are we looking at the same file? https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/fields.py

Comment: @poundifdef You are looking at the `main` branch, which is on its way to v2 and thus very different from the current stable version. [Here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/fields.py#L365) is the definition of `ModelField` in v1.10.7.

Answer (score -1):

The suggestion `typing.get_type_hints(Circle)` does what I wanted here (see [Pydantic get a fields type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68995170/pydantic-get-a-fields-type-hint)).

```
import typing
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Circle(BaseModel):
    radius: int
    pi: float = 3.14

typing.get_type_hints(Circle)
```

gives `{'radius': int, 'pi': float}`